# Counting raster values using another raster as mask in R?

Tags: raster, r, zonal-statistics, aggregation

I would like to count the frequency of values in one raster, using another raster (different resolution) as the zonal condition.

The premise is that the coarser resolution raster represents the area that I would like to count the frequency of the finer resolution raster;

```
# make 2 rasters of the same extent, different resolutions
ext <- extent(0,1000,0,1000)
r1 <- raster(nrows=1000, ncols=1000,ext)
r1[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 1000000, replace = TRUE)
r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r2[] <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
# create areas of interest in coarser raster
r2[r2 < 0.9] <- NA
```

Now i can't seem to find a function (might be blind) that will tell me what i want to know straight off - i thought zonal{raster} might have but it wont return a count function. So this is my work around:

```
# disaggregate the coarser raster to the same res as the finer raster
r2 <- disaggregate(r2,fact=c(100,100))
# mask the fine by the coarse 
r3 <- mask(r1,r2)
# and return a frequency table of the finer resolution
freq(r3,useNA="no")
```

But this seems a little round the houses.

ISSUE 1: Is there a function to zonal count in R with differing resolution rasters?

ISSUE 2: I up-scaled the above method to 2 very large rasters but got the error "Error: Failure during raster IO", why so?  ## FIXED: issue with PC, not R ##

ISSUE 3: what if I change each cell in the coarser resolution to have an ID instead of a value and I want to count the frequency of values in the finer res raster per ID?

(have also tried changing coarse res raster to binary 1/NA and multiplying but also get the same error as Issue 2 - im using a powerful computer that has worked with bigger data in big stacks, so the issue is not that).

Answer (score 4):

You could approach this as a raster/vector integration problem, where your course resolution data are essentially sampling blocks represented as polygons.

First, let's create your example data.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
ext <- extent(0,1000,0,1000)
  r1 <- raster(nrows=1000, ncols=1000,ext)
  r1[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 1000000, replace = TRUE)
  r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
  r2[] <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
  r2[r2 < 0.9] <- NA
```

Now we can coerce the coarse resolution raster to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

```
r2 <- rasterToPolygons(r2)
```

Using the raster::extract function  we create a list object of raster values for each polygon. We can then use apply calculate frequencies with table.

```
    r2.dat <- extract(r1, r2)  

# Just count values
( f <- do.call(rbind, lapply(r2.dat, FUN = function(x) { return( table(x)) })) ) 

# or, proportions
( f <- do.call(rbind, lapply(r2.dat, FUN = function(x) { return( prop.table(table(x))) })) )
```

The results will be ordered the same as the polygons and can be joined back to the polygon object. The only issue here is that the code is assuming that all values will be present in the frequencies. If this is not the case the vectors resulting from apply will not be equal. All you need to do if this error occurs is iterate through the list and add NA values where expected values are missing. You would need to write a function that is passed to lapply.

```
r2@data <- data.frame(r2@data, as.data.frame(f))
  names(r2@data)[2:ncol(r2)] <- paste( "value", colnames(f), sep=".") 
  r2@data
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm loathe to convert to vector when i'll be working with massive rasters, it's something i thought over in the original testing.

Comment: however, if there is no direct function for zonal stats (count) for rasters of two resolutions, then perhaps i'll have to test my work around vs your workaround and see what will work better after upscaling. Yours has the advantage of working per ID as well.

Comment: I looked at a way to keep the data raster but I believe that you will run into memory issues in short order.

Comment: depends, i have a lot of memory at my disposal

Comment: @JeffreyEvans: I know this is an old post, but I'm struggling with your last function to insert NAs where ther are missing values in the list. The line 

    r2@data <- data.frame(r2@data, as.data.frame(f))

returns "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 285504"

At first I thought "f" should be "r2.dat" since you mentioned iterating through the list, but that change also doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ecologist1234 It sounds like you are running into the NA issue I mentioned in the answer. If you look at nrow() of both of your objects you will see that they do not match. I would first check to see why extract is returning a null set. Perhaps your data is not overlapping. The list remains ordered to the sp object so it is easy to track down which feature is NA. You can always add an NA line into the data.frame that is being combined with your sp object.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans  Yes, it's definitely the NA issue you mentioned. Some of the But I think I don't understand how to fix it. The do.call(rbind.... should be making a freq table of the values of raster cells in each polygon. The problem, if I understand, is that some values don't show up in some polygons. Right? So, where do I add the NAs? To the list from extract or to the dataframe "f" from do.call?
Thanks for your help. Been puzzling over your code since yesterday. =/

Comment: @ecologist1234 I would really need to see your data to figure out how to fix your specific issue. Feel free to message me and provide a link to some example data. I can take a look today.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffreyEvans. In fact just solved it with different code and  input from a colleague. I appreciate the offer very, very much, though.